# Rails not converting time-only field to local time zone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3 and I realized that the fields of type TIME are not being transformed to the local time zone, but the DATETIME fields are.

For example, I've got the model `Promotion`, and it saves start/end dates separated from start/date times. On my mySQL database, there are four fields: `start_date`, `end_date`, `start_time`, `end_time`. `start_time` and `end_time` are saved with the server time, but when I want to get a promotion's attributes, those two are shown with the same value they have in the database.

Could anybody please tell me how to solve this?

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails DateTime treats dates by default in the current timezone. Time does not do this unless you explicitly tell it to do so. If you look at the documentation / code, you can see how DateTime uses Time and uses the current time zone explicitly.

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. So I'm using start_time.in_time_zone(Time.zone) and it's working. Thank you!